# Can I have XAMPP on localhost with web content hosted on Dropbox?

Tags: xampp, dropbox

I'm thinking of hosting WordPress on my Dropbox folder for development work. Has anyone tried this?

I'm wondering if there's a way to keep XAMPP on your local machine but direct the root to the Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, both WordPress and XAMPP produces a lot of garbage files (logs, PIDs, configs, sessions) etc. that will simply trashout your Dropbox. I'm pretty sure about that, because I tried to version XAMPP on SVN, which is pretty the same as SVN, and got really tired on searching more and more folders that should be ignored (non-versioned) because of containing data and other temp files.

And for answering your question. Sure thing, you can. After installing XAMPP (preferably outside Dropbox), go to "xampp\apache\conf" folder, edit "httpd.conf" file and change the value "DocumentRoot" variable (around line 90) to whatever you need. You may need to use ".." for specifying parent folder many times, if your Dropbox is outside XAMPP folder.

I won't discuss security matters here, as you should know, that such solution is highly risky and on the other side of security topics.

Comment: You can rid of the security risk by only hosting the files, none of the content. If someone steals my code, so be it.

Comment: I see your point. OK, I'm cool with that. Nevertheless, I gave you direct answer to your question, and hope this will help.